# Uploading a Parse.File with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, parse-platform, upload

How do I get the file from the form to save it to Parse?
I tried several dozen variations of this:

```
<form id="image_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/image" method="post">
          <h3>Upload icon image: </h3>
          <p><input id="image_file" name="image_file" type="file"></p>
          <p><input id="event_submit" type="submit" value="Create"  onclick="makeEventSnip();"></p>
</form>
```

and in the javascript:

```
function makeEventSnip() {
  event.preventDefault();

  var fileUploadControl = document.getElementById('image_file');
  var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
  var name = "icon.png";

  var iconImageFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
  alert(iconImageFile.getUrl());
```

I tried to do it the way they say to in Parse's JS Guide (https://parse.com/docs/js/guide) but that doesn't work either. It doesn't appear to be grabbing anything from the form. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 var fileUploadControl =  document.getElementById('image_file');
    var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
    var name = "icon.png";
    var iconImageFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
     iconImageFile.save().then(function() {//you need to call after save the file
      alert(iconImageFile._url);
     }
```